# Overlay an image on video in Android

Tags: android, video, overlay, ticker

I have been researching on this issue for a long time now. I am looking to develop a set-Top-Box like functionality for my app. Like a video is running on a TV. I want to  add an image as an overlay on this video just like a ticker.The  problem is my research so far shows that to overlay a view I need  to play video in my app and then I can do overlay on video and this is what I have achieved till now. My app is supposed to run on an Android set-Top-Box and the video is not being played in my app its being played on TV. Is there any technique I can render that image as an  overlay on video in TV. I have tried approaches like Including a view inside another and then using alpha property I can give it an overlay effect and I have even tried ticker examples. Any approach/technique to show image on video as an overlay or ticker being played outside my app?? Forgive me if it seem a little complicated to understand lemme Know if any clarifications required..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Stephan Branczyk: Thank you for your such a great effort..:)

Comment: @kenorb: I did ask it on stackexchange.com few days back but did not get any response there so I had no other option

Comment: I am pretty new on this platform so have a little mercy..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. This is the way to do it:

https://github.com/entertailion/Overlay-for-GTV

> **Overlay Effects for Google TV**
>
> Live TV effects for Google TV. Configure
>   various effects to be displayed periodically when watching live TV on
>   your Google TV device. You can choose to see the effects every half
>   hour or at the top of the hour.
>
> If you change the configuration and then go to live TV, you should see
>   a preview of the effects after a few seconds.
>
> This app is available for free in the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.entertailion.android.overlay).
>
> Developers:
>
> - The code is released under the Apache 2.0 open source license. **The
>     source code is commented to explain the design.**

Comment: Thaks a ton for the quick reply. I will try this and get back to you...:)